# On Linux, what is the size of pages reported by vmstat command and/or /proc/vmstat?

Tags: linux, vmstat, paging

As many have stated on StackExchange and elsewhere, a typical kernel/mmu page size for Linux is 4 KiB.  I have verified that this is the case on my OS/architecture (RHEL 6.6, Intel Xeon E5-2690).

Now among other things, the `vmstat -s` command reports on "pages paged in" and "pages paged out", which are counters that start from 0 at boot time.  I have confirmed that at any given moment, these values are exactly equal to the values found for the `pgpgin` and `pgpgout` entries in **`/proc/vmstat`** (does vmstat command get them from `/proc/vmstat`?).  Other commands, and in particular `sar -B` report `pgpgin/s` and `pgpgout/s` as Kibibytes paged in/out per second during a particular interval.

In recent tests, I have seen that `pgpgin/s` and `pgpgout/s` values from sar also correspond exactly to a rate calculated from vmstat values for a specified interval.  This leads me to conclude that vmstat is reporting values for pages of 1 KiB in size.  Thus the `pgpgin/out` values of **`/proc/vmstat`** are the number of KiB paged in/out since boot.

My questions are:

1. Is this a valid conclusion, and
2. If so, why do vmstat and other facilities report in 1 KiB pages instead of the 4 KiB pages that are the "common currency" of the OS and architecture?  In particular, vmstat is saying "`pages paged in/out`", not "`KiBs paged in/out`".  This is confusing.

Comment: Side note: 4 KiB is a ridiculously small page size, so I expect it to become less and less "common".

Answer (score 4):

In regards to the counters in `/proc/vmstat` the function that appears to update these values is `submit_bio` in `Linux/block/blk-core.c`.

```
2067 blk_qc_t submit_bio(struct bio *bio)
2068 {
...
2079                         count = bio_sectors(bio);
2080 
2081                 if (op_is_write(bio_op(bio))) {
2082                         count_vm_events(PGPGOUT, count);
2083                 } else {
2084                         task_io_account_read(bio->bi_iter.bi_size);
2085                         count_vm_events(PGPGIN, count);
2086                 }
...
2100 }
2101 EXPORT_SYMBOL(submit_bio);
```

`bio_sectors` is a macro in `Linux/include/linux/bio.h`

```
 64 #define bio_sectors(bio)        ((bio)->bi_iter.bi_size >> 9)
```

This seems to suggest to me that the numbers are counted in sector sizes (512) bytes. Given thats what value you'd end up getting if you right shifted a byte count by nine.

This appears to be a similar setup between kernels 2.6.27 - 4.0.x anyways.